# To send edited Image to next activity

Tags: android, draw, paint

I have Written the code to draw the text on the image and to send it to next activity.
In same activity it is showing the image but in next activity it is not showing the image.

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(photo);
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                paint.setStrokeWidth(12); // Text Size
                canvas.drawBitmap(photo, 0, 0, paint);
                canvas.drawText(topaste, 15, 150, paint);
                image.setImageBitmap(photo);
                Intent i1=new Intent(FullScreen.this,EditImage.class);
                i1.putExtra("photoo", photo);
                startActivity(i1);
```

and Receiving activity is

```
image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        photo = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("photooo");
        image.setImageBitmap(photo);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled your keyword when you retrieved your extra.  When you put the photo into the intent, you used "photoo" and when you get it in the next activity you used "photooo".

Comment: If I want to save it in sdcard then what addition I have to do

Answer (score 1):

this happens because photoo != photooo

Comment: I think it'a good idea to use constants when dealing with these keys. It can be a good way to avoid such errors